# Multiple results for Voice Recognition in Android

Tags: android

Hi I am trying to get multiple values from the Android voice recognition, not just the best one.

I think I have to add one more flag, but I am not used to the android way of doing things.
So far this is what I have:

(thanks)

```
private OnClickListener mSpeakListener = new OnClickListener(){     
    public void onClick(View v){
        if (v.getId() == R.id.speech) {
            bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Fire an intent to start the speech recognition activity.
 */
private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra( RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,                          
                     RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech recognition demo");
    startActivityForResult(intent,0);

}

/**
* Handle the results from the recognition activity.
*/
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it could have heard
       ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       for(String match: matches){
           sb.append(match + ", ");
       }
       questionTextBox.setText(sb.toString());
       Log.d(TAG,"Focus on Button");
       okButton.requestFocus();           
   }
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The flag you are looking for is `EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS`

If you wanted up to 10 results, your code would then look like this:

```
private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra( RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,                          
                     RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,10);      //newly added flag
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech recognition demo");
    startActivityForResult(intent,0);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: great response! A good answer has a specific answer and provides a snippet of code.

Comment: This always give 5 results to me. Why is that?

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, I added the EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS flag and still receive only one result while offline, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to ask here, do you get an error or are you just asking for clarification on what the code does?

[I wrote a newbies guide](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-how-to-implement-voice-recognition-a-nice-easy-tutorial/) on voice recognition, that may help you

Regards

Comment: I think he/she means he is getting one result, instead of an ArrayList of possible results. But correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: What words are you trying to use? If its something small like "I" then maybe you will only get 1 result.

Comment: Can you give us some examples of what your speaking into the device? I'd like to try myself. Also have you tried the WEB FORM instead of free form? Wonder if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing it right. In the [sample of the demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html), shows all the matches.
Try using the `VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE` value they use: `1234`.

**Edited:**
Well you were right about `REQUEST_CODE`, but your code, which is actually almost the same given on the Demos, works perfectly for me. Could it be a Service itself issue? What language are you using?

Regards.

Comment: Request codes have nothing to do with it, that is just for when you receive results to know who started it